# Register button in my Login App does nothing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-studio-2.1

I followed a tutorial on how to create a login application. I double checked my codes and I followed everything. But when I tried to click on the Register button, nothing happened. I tried to put some toast messages if it fails or succeeds but still nothing happens. this is my Register.class

```
public class Register extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText Reg_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Reg_username);
    final EditText Reg_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Reg_pass);
    final EditText Reg_conpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Reg_conpass);
    final EditText Reg_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Reg_name);
    final Button Reg_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Reg_button);

    Reg_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = Reg_name.getText().toString();
            final String username = Reg_username.getText().toString();
            final String password = Reg_pass.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if(success){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this,LogInActivity.class);
                                Register.this.startActivity(intent);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                };
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);




        }
    });
}
```

}

and this is my RegisterRequest.class

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://www.puc.gava.ph/Register.php";
private Map<String,String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String username, String password, String name, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST,REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name",name);
    params.put("username",username);
    params.put("password",password);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: unfortunately, still can't. I've seen in the comments they have same issues. But the video uploader didn't reply. I'm just trying to find different ways to complete my app. I can't really debug my code since I'm just a beginner and this site is my only hope for uncertainties. thanks for your concern.

Comment: What happens if you declare the `Response.Listener`, the `RegisterRequest` and the `RequestQueue` as class variables? My guess is that right now they stop existing as soon as `onClick()` finishes.